# Yii2: url managment for the search url

Tags: search, yii2

I've been trying to change the URL, that's being displayed when you search for something, a while back and couldn't get it done.

The URL looks like this:

```
?PostSearch%5Btitle%5D=&PostSearch%5Bbody%5D=test&PostSearch%5Bcreated_at%5D=
```

using PostSearch and the search term "test".

I wanted to hide PostSearch and overall change the way things were being displayed (the arrays, the pattern, ...) but I found no documentation about the search.

I hope someone can answer me this.
Thanks.

*(Used framework - Yii2)*

Comment: Are you using gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method into your form model (PostSearch)

```
public function formName()
{
    return '';
}
```